# Setting parameter value dependently on the group in rdlc report C#

Tags: c#, rdlc

Is it possible to change the parameter value dependently on the group that the parameter is in. This is the case. My report gets grouped by serial numbers of items and I would like to display some additional informations in the group's first row - I use that row as a certain header. Of course that informations are different for each value, so how can I change them depending on that value. Let me give you an example - let's say that item under serial number 1111 is a computer and I track when it was used - when I display my report the group looks like this.

```
1111
     Logged on | Logged off
          Data      Data
            .         .
            .         .
```

Let's say that another item is a printer, and it has a serial number is 2222. When I display the report for both items (the individual reports work just fine) it looks like this:

```
1111         [MyParameter]
         Logged on  |  Logged off
          DateTime      DateTime
                .         .
                .         . 
[Page break]

2222      [MyParameter]
        PrintingStarted | PrintingEnded
           DateTime          DateTime    
               .                .
               .                .
```

I want MyParameter to say "Computer" in the 1111 group and "Printer" in 2222 group. How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your serial number comes from a field name SerialNumber, you could use an expression along these lines to define the value of [MyParameter] :

```
=Switch(Fields!SerialNumber.Value = 1111, "Computer", Fields!SerialNumber.Value = 2222, "Printer")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would it be possible to do it from the code of the application, because I have too many items to manually write them all in this manner?

Comment: Does the text that you want to display come from a database ?

Comment: Yes, every item is listed in a table in a database (in the table I use for my reports every item is represented by serial number, but there is another table that contains the serial number and name of each item). 
P.S The code you gave me works fine, and it might serve as a temporary solution, but I need a way to automatically add or remove items as they change in the database

Comment: Then why don't you retrieve the name of the item in your query by joining your two tables ? It would be the most efficient solution since you have to read from the database anywyays. No additional code required, your reports are always up to date and so on.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake, there is another table that has to be used (3 in total). The first one tracks the usage of a certain item (represented by its serial number) the second one holds the serial number of the item and a ID number of that item and the third one holds ID and name of that item (don't ask me why, I did not design the database, but I have to use it like that). How would the SQL query that returns Serial Number from first and Name from third table look like. This is very complex, so please help me. Thanks